# Details are visible in my request, how do I filter this in my API request?

Tags: api

This is my first time working with an API and the various sources have been very helpful.However I am now struggling at the end.

**API:** Vincere API

**API Documentation:** https://api.vincere.io/documentation.html#tag/Introduction

**What I am trying to do:** The client has a list of jobs shown on their dashboard when logged in. On the dashboard there is a column listed as "Posted", this data below is then either "Posted" or "Not Posted". I would like to retrieve all jobs that are only listed as "Posted".

**What I am able to do:**
I am able to connect, authenticate and get the required data using the above documentation. I can then see whether a job should be private or public.

**Problem I am facing:**
I would like to only show the jobs that have

```
"private_job": 0,
```

At the moment my request is returning all jobs.

**The request I am sending::**

```
https://companyname.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=created_date dec?limit=100
```

**Result**

```
{
"result": {
    "start": 0,
    "total": 355,
    "items": [
        {
            "private_job": 0,
            "job_title": "HR Manager"
        },
        {
            "private_job": 0,
            "job_title": "Accountant / Financial Manager - Cryptocurrency"
        },
        {
            "private_job": 1,
            "job_title": "Conveyancer"
        },
```

**What I have tried:**
From reading some other questions and articles I tried the following but the result remained unchanged

```
https://companyname.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=created_date dec?limit=100&private_job=0
```

**Result**

```
{
"result": {
    "start": 0,
    "total": 355,
    "items": [
        {
            "private_job": 0,
            "job_title": "HR Manager"
        },
        {
            "private_job": 0,
            "job_title": "Accountant / Financial Manager - Cryptocurrency"
        },
        {
            "private_job": 1,
            "job_title": "Conveyancer"
        },
```

I also tried:

```
https://companyname.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=created_date dec?limit=100&private_job=false
```

**Result**
Same as above

I would really appreciate some assistance with the above. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `private_job` to the `q` (query list). So I thinkwhat you're after is something like:

```
https://companyname.vincere.io/api/v2/job/search/fl=job_title,private_job;sort=created_date desc?q=private_job:0%23&limit=100
```